How to extract last folder name on Windows with cmd?
I am trying to create a Sublime Build system for Windows, where last folder name should be used.
The existing variables don't provide me with the last folder name, so I have to use $folder, which contains the full path, for ex., C:\Users\username\Dev\Project\somename, when I need just somename. I tried to use the following command:
for %%f in ("%MYDIR1%") do set "myfolder=%%~nxf"

the problem here is with the following usage of result. I have to use one line for all commands (see shell_cmd description), so the result line looked like the following:
"shell_cmd": "(for %%f in ("$folder") do set \"myfolder=%%~nxf\") && (echo %myfolder%)"

But it doesn't work, %myfolder% doesn't contain the needed value.
What else could be done?

does this help?

If we look at the documentation on Build Systems, we see that we can use snippet substitution in the variables used in the build system. This is really handy when the built-in variables don't quite meet our needs.
Therefore, we can replace everything up to the last slash with nothing to get the last component of the path.
I find the easiest way to test substitutions is using a snippet for $SELECTION, so you can just change the selected text and try a different test case, without needing to worry about saving the file with different names or running the build system and waiting for the results.
The substitution is done with regular expressions, where forward slashes need to be escaped, as they have special meaning. One slash after the variable name, one slash after the find regex pattern, one slash after that, followed by the replacement pattern, followed by a slash to indicate the end of the replacement pattern and optionally followed by some regex flags. Therefore, the snippet I'm using is:
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
${SELECTION/^.*\\//}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>

This just matches from the beginning of the string (^), then any character greedily until it finds a literal \. As we are only expecting one match, we don't need to use the global regex modifier flag. So the last / delimited section is empty.
The output we get from that with a selection of C:\Users\username\Dev\Project\somename is:

somename


(To apply the snippet, assuming you saved it in Packages/User as something like last_path_component.sublime-snippet, you can just type last path in the Command Palette and it will find it.)
So, now we have a working variable replacement regex, we can just take the variable part out of the snippet, and replace SELECTION with folder, so it will operate on the current folder path instead of the selection, just like you had originally, and plug that into your build system:
    "shell_cmd": "echo ${folder/^.*\\//}"


Fantastic! Didn't new there is another documentation for build systems. Many thanks!
